# React-awsome-animation module has error that 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RevealProps' in react version 18

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, animation

I 'm going to scroll animation with react-awesome-reveal module.
I have used this module in React typescript before.
but i didn't see error like this.
please help me to solve this bugs.

Error msg is like this.

```
Type '{ children: Element; keyframes: Keyframes; triggerOnce: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RevealProps'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RevealProps'.ts(2322)
```

Code is like this

```
    import { Reveal } from "react-awesome-reveal";
import { customizeAnimation } from "config/utils";

export const example = () => {
  return (
    <Reveal keyframes={ customizeAnimation } triggerOnce>
      <div>{some childrens}</div>
    </Reveal>
  );
};
```